# Why does this code work in IE but not in Google Chrome?

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void GVTraderdueReport_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GVTraderdueReport.EditIndex = -1;
    GettraderwiseLiftingRecords();
}
protected void GVTraderdueReport_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    GVTraderdueReport.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GettraderwiseLiftingRecords();
}

protected void GVTraderdueReport_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtrecamount = (TextBox)GVTraderdueReport.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[1];
    TextBox txtrecdate = (TextBox)GVTraderdueReport.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[1];
    TextBox txtchknumber = (TextBox)GVTraderdueReport.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[1];
    TextBox txtremark = (TextBox)GVTraderdueReport.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[1];


    string tradername = Convert.ToString(GVTraderdueReport.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());

    IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
    String recdate1 = txtrecdate.Text.Trim().ToString();
    DateTime recdate2 = DateTime.Parse(recdate1, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);


    objhatcheryPL.name = tradername;
    objhatcheryPL.cashrec = Convert.ToInt32(txtrecamount.Text.ToString());
    objhatcheryPL.recdate = recdate2;
    objhatcheryPL.chequeno = txtchknumber.Text.ToString();
    objhatcheryPL.remark = txtremark.Text.ToString();
    objhatcheryPL.username = Session["username"].ToString();

    int? chkduetatus;
    chkduetatus = objhatcheryBAL.updateChicksalesDueReport(objhatcheryPL);

    if (chkduetatus.Equals(1))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "SelectDetails", "alert('Updated Successful');", true);
    }
    GVTraderdueReport.EditIndex = -1;
    GettraderwiseLiftingRecords();

}

protected void GVTraderdueReport_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToUpper() == "VIEWHISTORY")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        int index = row.RowIndex;
        string farmername = Convert.ToString(GVTraderdueReport.DataKeys[index].Value);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Open", "window.open('../Reports/viewHatcherysalesdueentry.aspx?name=" + farmername + "', '_blank', 'dependent,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=0,height=600');", true);
    }
}
```

it is working in internet exploral but in google crome it's not working. what is the problem iam not getting. i had written code in master page. if i click on edit button, update and cancel buttons are releasing but they are not responding when i click on that,similarly GO button. please can any one help me.

Comment: maybe you can tell us what it actually does.

Comment: i want to update/cancel the columns recieved amount,recieved date,cheque no/cash and Remark  in grid and if i click on GO button it will display one popupwindow but these buttons are not working google crome

Comment: checked that all popup-blocker mechanisms are disabled on chrome ? ;-)

Comment: i had removed updatepanel and content template in .aspx page(client side) now it is working in google chrome also.